# When do I use a comma before a pronoun?

Tags: grammar, commas

I'm writing a report about a book. One of the sentences reads "The Outsiders is a book written by Susan Eloise Hinton, who is more commonly known by her pen name of S. E. Hinton." At the word "who", do I use a comma before it?

Comment: Yes. Presumably there is only one Susan Eloise Hinton, so a defining relative clause (the kind without a comma) is not needed to identify which person is being referred to.

Comment: IMO it is incorrect to say that S.E. Hinton is the *pen name* of Susan Eloise Hinton. That's one format of her *real* name. A [**pen name**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pen_name) is a pseudonym such as Lewis Carroll, the pen name of Charles Dodgson. So "The Outsiders is a book written by Susan Eloise Hinton, commonly known as S. E. Hinton" or even "The Outsiders is a book written by S.E. Hinton, full name Susan Eloise Hinton."

Comment: The comma indicates that what follows is not restrictive. There is an assumption that there is only one Susan Eloise Hinton. If there actually happened to be two or more people by that name, and you needed to specify *which* one you were talking about (the one who goes by S.E. Hinton as opposed to the one who goes by a different name), then you would not use the comma. If you can put everything that follows the comma in parentheses (as an aside), then the comma is appropriate. If you *can't*, because what follows it is *required* for understanding, then the comma should not be there.